Water to water heat exchange through copper coil
To provide a closed loop heated water line to support a radiator, for example,
using a water-filled copper coil immersed in an open-air bath of water,
where heat transfer from one volume of water to the other should take place, is it better

to heat the bath directly and run the coil content as the radiator heating fluid, or
to heat the water in the coil and use the bath content as the radiator heating fluid

Option 1 I think would need to operate at lower temperature given that it is open to the air, and
Option 2 represents a high-temperature low-volume heat source
Which is a better design in general, before I come to the questions of flow rates and energy consumption ?
At this point I want to just focus on the physics of the transfer and what might be a better general design; I wish to avoid topics like hygiene or glycol-v-water for the time being.
